# Double.doubleToLongBits equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, java, double, long-integer, bit

there's a Java method `Double.doubleToLongBits` that basically gets a `double` and return a `long` with the same bits.
How can I do it in C#?
Thank you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits` would be a good alternative.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.doubletoint64bits.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You'll want [BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.doubletoint64bits.aspx)