# Communicate with java server over tcp from c#

Tags: java, c#, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I'm playing a little with TCP servers and clients and I was trying to communicate with a Java server from a c# application but I can't manage to get it to work.

I'm using a Multithreaded Server for my Java Server (thread a connection).
I read the inputstream and write the outputstream using DataInputStream and DataOutputStream. Here is the code I am using to receive incoming Packages

```
DataInputStream ois = null;
DataOutputStream oos = null;


ois  = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
oos = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());


        while(clientSocket.isConnected())
        {
            while(ois.available() > 0)
            {
                byte id = ois.readByte();

                Package p = MultiThreadedServer.getPackageHandler().getPackage(id);

                if(p != null)
                {
                    p.handle(ois, oos);
                    System.out.println("Request processed with id: " + id);
                }

              }
          }
```

When I was connecting with this server through java I used to sent data this way:

```
DataOutputStream oos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
oos.writeByte(5);
oos.writeByte(3); // user_ID

oos.flush();
```

And then I was reading the input in the server by searching for a package with the same id as the incoming byte sent  oos.writeByte(5); 
Here is my Package class

```
    public abstract class Package
{
    private int id = 0;

    public Package(int id){ this.id = id; }

    public abstract void handle(DataInputStream ois, DataOutputStream oos) throws Exception;

    public int getID()
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

An example of how I read the incoming data :

```
@Override
                    public void handle(DataInputStream ois, DataOutputStream oos) throws Exception
                    {

                        int user_id = ois.readByte();
                        System.out.println("Handle package 1 " + user_id);

                        ResultSet rs = cm.execute("SELECT TOP 1 [id] ,[username] FROM [Database].[dbo].[users] WHERE [id] = '"+ user_id +"'");

                        while (rs.next())
                        {
                            oos.writeByte((getID() + (byte)999));
                            oos.writeUTF(rs.getString(2));
                            oos.flush();
                        }

                    }
```

This was working fine in Java only but how can I send data like this using c# ?
I need a function that can do this:

```
DataOutputStream oos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    oos.writeByte(5);
    oos.writeByte(3); // user_ID

    oos.flush();
```

or something but then in c# but the NetworkStream class in c# does not support this so how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what is not supported on the NetworkStream in C#. You pass your socket in the Constructor and send the data with `WriteByte()`. Also `Flush()` is available.

So it would look like this:

```
var oos = new NetworkStream(socket);
oos.WriteByte(5);
oos.WriteByte(3); // user_ID
oos.Flush();
```

To write floats or doubles, you have to convert them yourself:

```
double a = 1.1;
long a_as_long = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(a);
byte[] a_as_bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(a_as_long);
oos.Write(a_as_bytes, 0, a_as_bytes.Length)
```

Comment: Okay, maybe I expressed it wrong. The WriteByte functie is actually okay. but I also need functions like writeDouble , writeFloat & writeUTF. And those do not exists in the Networkstream class. My example wasn't the best one ;) Or can use writeByte everytime and in the server cast it to double ? I'm not experienced with this

Comment: No, but you can read the matching number of bytes. Then you can convert them to int or long and then use this ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816691/double-doubletolongbits-equivalent-in-c or it oposite equivalent) to convert it to double.

Comment: extended the answer with writing a double to the stream